# JSTL variables doesn't working

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I got a problem , I declared a variable at the top of the JSP page , but when I try to use it , is appears that it is not working !

```
<c:set var="req" value="${pageContext.request}" />
<c:set var="baseURL" value="${req.scheme}://${req.serverName}:${req.serverPort}${req.contextPath}" />
```

Now am trying to print the variable (baseUrl) in this way :

```
${baseUrl}
```

but nothing appears !

Here is the header for JSP :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

What is the mistake ?

Comment: test the values , you add to the variables one by one or try <c:set var="baseURL" value="1"/> for example then the problem is in your values

Comment: I did that @Dunken , the same problem !

Comment: @Dunken , I did all that my friend ! , even I make new var with simple value , all that does nothing !

Comment: @Dunken but for original variables it is working well , e.g    ${pageContext.request.contextPath}

Comment: Look You are setting variable named baseURL and trying to retrieve ${baseUrl}. May be that might be the problem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The answer was in the letter case. It should be :

```
${baseURL}
```

I know already about the case , but this is one problems you face when you try to code once you're tired !